# Best data structure and design for this feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I have a section called Situations, which is basically a textual description of a situation. But there are several of them. I want to be able to display **only one at a time and each one on its own page** (the newest created ones first), and then at the bottom of the page I have links that go to Older and Newer situations.

Assume that I have a `@situations` object in my code that contains all the situations that I want to display. What should I do next (in the controller and the view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use pagination ([`will_paginate`](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/master)) and set the number of items per page to 1.

Then you can use `current_page` and `next_page` to make your links.  See [source](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/8888651be8d6656bdf2378731d91a8badbaa2556/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb) here.

Other that it would just be a standard index action with the changes made required for `will_paginate`.

This [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate) should give you a good idea what you need but be aware that there have been some changes to the plugin since it was made.  Details are on the [`will_paginate` github wiki.](http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will_paginate/simple-search)

Comment: Here: http://gitrdoc.com/rdoc/mislav/will_paginate/8888651be8d6656bdf2378731d91a8badbaa2556/classes/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers.html#M000131 on the bottom is information how to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Nice.  How did you find that rdoc?

Answer (score 1):

models/situation.rb

```
class Situation < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'created_at desc'
end
```

controllers/situations_controller.rb

```
class SituationsController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @situations = Situation.all
  end
end
```

views/situations/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Situations</h1>
<%= render @situations %>
```

views/situations/_situation.html.erb

```
<h2><%= situation.name -%></h2>
<p><%= situation.description -%></p>
```

Comment: What about the links at the bottom? One situation per page.